# How to install Cypress from local zip file using npm

Tags: installation, cypress

I wanted to install Cypress using npm - but my corporate firewall is blocking.

So I tried the below method in my Terminal in Visual Studio Code - But getting an error (pasted below)

Any idea on why this script does not work? and solution to it?

PS C:\Users\c64881a\Desktop\NPM_Cypress> **CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=C:/Users/c64881a/Downloads/cypress.zip npm install cypress**

CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=C:/Users/c64881a/Downloads/cypress.zip : The term 'CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=C:/Users/c64881a/Downloads/cypress.zip' is not recognized as
the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=C:/Users/c64881a/Downloads/cypress.zip npm ins ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CYPRESS_INSTALL...ads/cypress.zip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: That's not how you set environment variables on Windows.

Comment: maybe try putting the path to cypress.zip in quotes? Also it looks like you are in powershell, try using cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this in **PowerShell**:

```
setx CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY C:/Users/c64881a/Downloads/cypress.zip
```